# How to get occurrences of string lengths for a column of strings in postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql

Given an input of a text/string column, I want to compute the lengths of the strings in the columns, and the counts for each length.

E.g. a column with the strings:

```
'Ant'
'Cat'
'Dog'
'Human'
''
NULL
'A human'
```

Would give:

```
0 : 1
3 : 3
5 : 1
7 : 1
```

NOTE: the null string hasn't been counted as a 0 character string, but ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length()` comes to mind:

```
select length(col), count(*)
from t
where col is not null
group by length(col)
order by length(col);
```

Comment: Thanks, trying this now